# Use the sessions in the test - Play Framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, session, playframework-2.0

I want to create a fake session on my junit test but i can't...

I have some methods protect by @With to protect each method, the value to acces to the methods protected by @With is on the session,

on the the session if the value of "member_running=1" and
"project_running=1" the function addBacklog work and the http status is 200, ifelse the http status is 401 ( Unauthorized )

on this exemple i want to create a session test

```
 @Test
public void testSession() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            session.put("member_running","1");
            session.put("project_running","1");
            Result res = route(fakeRequest("GET", "/")
                    .method("POST")
                    //.session("member_running","1")
                    //.session("project_running","1")
                    .session(session)
                    .uri(routes.ProductBacklogController.addBacklog("MyName","MyPriority","MyFirstEstimate","MyDescription").url()));
            assertEquals("This is not the page addBacklog","/projectus/backlog/add/MyName/MyPriority/MyFirstEstimate/MyDescription", request.uri());

            assertEquals("The page should be work", 200, res.status());

        }
    });

}
```

On my reserach i found the method .withSession("key","value") and he doesn't work, i've try to replace this with just .session("key,"value) ( like the exemple above)

Now i have try to use se session of res with :

```
res.session();
```

but it return : {}

And

```
res.status();
```

return : 401
because the session is not used.

the session contains :

```
{connected=true, lastName=Crenn, firstName=Thomas, nav=open, member_running=1, project=[{"project":"ProjectUS","project_id":1,"members":[{"member":"DEVELOPER","member_id":2},{"member":"ADMINISTRATOR","member_id":3},{"member":"PRODUCT_OWNER","member_id":4},{"member":"SCRUM_MASTER","member_id":5}]},{"project":"ScrumBadass","project_id":2,"members":[{"member":"SCRUM_MASTER","member_id":9},{"member":"DEVELOPER","member_id":10}]}], cip=2, project_running=1}
```

And for information the version of play framework is 2.5